# Docker container not connecting to docker container db

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb, dockerfile

I have two docker containers being built using docker compose. One is a mariadb and the other is a web api made using python. When I startup the mariadb container then run the application from my desktop all works fine and dandy. However when I run both containers I get the error:

```
 pymysql.err.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' ([Errno 111] Connection refused)")
```

I have tried all sorts of things to get it to run but I cannot seem to figure it out.
In my SQL setup I have done:

```
CREATE USER 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';
```

The line that connects to the db in python is:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", database="cs3743_pwu657", port=3306)
```

It seems like my api container can't reach the mariadb container for some reason or that it is not being let in for whatever reason. I am not sure what I need to change to fix this.

**Docker File for api**

```
FROM pwu657/docker-api
WORKDIR /app
COPY src ./src
RUN pip3 install -r ./src/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install Werkzeug
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["python3", "./src/webapi.py"]
```

**Docker File for DB**

```
FROM mariadb
COPY ./setup.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/setup.sql
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=howdy
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3.9"
volumes:
  pwu657-db-vol: {}

services:
  pwu657-db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-db
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - pwu657-db-vol:/var/lib/mysql

  pwu657-api:
    build:
      network: host
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-api
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - pwu657-db
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    links:
      - "pwu657-db"
```

And like I said it has no problem connecting when I run the api from my IDE but when I start the docker container it refuses the connection

Comment: In docker(-compose) world, `127.0.0.1` relates to the container where the code/service/whatever is running. Since you map the db port to your local machine (i.e. `3306:3306` in your `docker-compose.yml` file), this port is accessible as `localhost` from your own operating system. Not anymore when you are in your api container. `docker-compose` manages hostnames for you. Simply replace `127.0.0.1` with => `pwu657-db` in your python connection config and your problem should be fixed.

Comment: I was actually just now getting on to answer my own question with that. I did exactly that and it worked but I forgot to ever come back and answer until now.

Answer (score 0):

Since connecting from `pwu657-api` to `127.0.0.1` means this machine itself, you should change your database connection line in python to:

```
db = pymysql.connect(host="pwu657-db", user="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", database="cs3743_pwu657", port=3306)
```